# this.state is not working on reader.onload funtion in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to set state, but `this.state` is not working, can anyone please check this code, and help me what's issue in that, here is my code

```
save_import_permit() {
      //alert('sdsdsd');
      var file_name =  jQuery('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop(); //jQuery('#permit_csv_file').prop('files')[0];
      let files = jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];
      console.log(files);      
      let reader = new FileReader();  
      let data = [];
      reader.readAsDataURL(files);
      reader.onload = function(e) {    
        console.log(e.target.result);   
        data.result = e.target.result;
        data.action = 'Permity::saveImportCsvFile';  
        const url  = 'admin-ajax.php';
        const formdata = "file="+data.result+"&action="+data.action;       
        this.state({loading:'loading_show'})    
        return post(url,formdata,function (r) {
          this.state({loading:'loading_hide'});        
          alert(r.data.msg)          
        }.bind(this));   
      }.bind(this);     

  }
```

Comment: change `this.state` to `this.setState`

Comment: Now state is working ut not getting alert, can you please help me

Comment: I am getting success response of ajax but not getting that alert, can you please help me why not getting alert for that

Comment: try `console.log()`to see if you get it

Comment: I checked it is not workin

Comment: what does `post(url,formdata,function (r) {
          this.state({loading:'loading_hide'});        
          alert(r.data.msg)          
        }.bind(this))` do? Show more about this `post(...)` function

Comment: It is working now thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't attribute a value to the state using `this.state`, you should always use `this.setState()`, wichs is a build-in function of the react framework. Check this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) to know better.

So you need to change

`this.state({loading:'loading_show'})`

to

`this.setState({loading:'loading_show'})`

Comment: Yes now state is working, but i am not getting alert even of ajax success response

Comment: the `alert()` is inside `post(...)` and I can't know why the alert is not showing if you don't give more information about it